# Как получить элемент на форме из библиотеки?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я создал Windows Form Application и подключил к ней новую пустую библиотеку и я могу использовать классы этой библиотеки на Form1, а мне нужно, чтобы я мог в классе этой библиотеки использовать элементы, которые находятся на форме скажем PictureBox.

Видел что-то такое:

```
public PictureBox getPictureBox() 
{
    return pictureBox1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конкретное имя экземпляра контрола, который будет расположен на форме, вы можете задать в дизайнере. По умолчанию, это, видимо, pictureBox1. Если определить метод, предложенным вами способом, то он будет возвращать ссылку экзепляр и с ним можно будет работать.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplicationX
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public PictureBox getPictureBox() 
        {
            return pictureBox1;
        }
    }
}
```